# How to run a Google Earth Engine script locally

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

I am new to Google Earth Engine. I have been using the [Google Earth Engine code editor](https://earthengine.google.com/platform/) to create and run my scripts. However, this approach doesn't scale.

I have a script that gets the precipitation data for a region and exports it as a .csv to Google Drive. I want to know if there is a way to run the script locally rather than on the Google Earth Engine code editor. Instead of storing the .csv output in Google Drive, I can even store it in my local file system if that simplifies things.

```
var grids = ee.FeatureCollection("users/ramaraja/grids");

var gridCode = 13885;
var grid_13885 = grids.filter(ee.Filter.eq('GRIDCODE',gridCode));

var chirps2021_1 = ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/PENTAD')
            .filterDate('2021-01-01', '2021-02-28')
            .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,2,'month'))
            .filterBounds(grid_13885);

var chirps2021_1_sum = ee.Image(chirps2021_1.sum())

var chirps2021_1_sum_13885 = chirps2021_1_sum.clip(grid_13885);

var precipitationVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 112.0,
  palette: ['001137', '0aab1e', 'e7eb05', 'ff4a2d', 'e90000'],
};

Map.addLayer(chirps2021_1_sum_13885, precipitationVis, "Sum January & February 2021 Precipitation", true, 1.0);

Map.centerObject(grid_13885, 0);

var pixels = chirps2021_1_sum_13885.multiply(10).toInt().reduceToVectors({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.countEvery(),
  geometry: grid_13885,
  scale: 5566,
  geometryType: 'centroid',
  labelProperty: 'precipitation',
  });

var proj = chirps2021_1_sum_13885.select([0]).projection()
var latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat()
chirps2021_1_sum_13885 = chirps2021_1_sum_13885.addBands(latlon.select('longitude','latitude'))

pixels=chirps2021_1_sum_13885.select('longitude').reduceRegions(pixels, ee.Reducer.first().setOutputs(['long']), 25)
pixels=chirps2021_1_sum_13885.select('latitude').reduceRegions(pixels, ee.Reducer.first().setOutputs(['lat']), 25);
pixels=chirps2021_1_sum_13885.select('precipitation').reduceRegions(pixels, ee.Reducer.first().setOutputs(['precipitation']), 25);

Map.addLayer(pixels,{}, 'grids')

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: pixels,
  description: 'grid_13885',
  selectors: ['system:index','precipitation','lat','long',],
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Here's a visualization of the output,

[image]

The asset, `users/ramaraja/grids` is a shapefile I uploaded to Google Earth Engine.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is:

- you can run some GEE code locally by connecting your computer to the GEE API ([Python](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/intro-to-python-api))
- This code will still be run on Google servers so any scale limitation you faced will still be an issue. Note that for that many workaround exist as the [tiling system proposed by Noel Golerick](https://gorelick.medium.com/fast-er-downloads-a2abd512aa26)
- Google prevent you from exprting directl to your local computer. The trick is usually to get a download url and get the data using Python `requests` lib